# Longest Common Subsequence for more than 2 strings

Tags: c++, string, sequence

How to find the [LCS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-subsequence-dp-4/) (Longest Common Subsequence) for more than two strings? We can solve for the LCS for two strings with DP, but how to proceed for LCS for more than two strings?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's the best answer, but I guess a DP approach could work here as well. With 2 strings you make a 2D array and fill it with "match lengths" for different starting/ending indeces of both strings (depending on your approach). You could just use ND array for N strings, and fill it in the same way.

Comment: Can you provide some kind of algorithm or some code for lets say LCS for 3 strings.

Comment: I may try to think about something like that this evening. I'll post some code then.